# scrape articles from html to json

Tags: html, json, scrape

I have this code

```
    $result['meta'] ['product-name'] ['item'] = $html->find('td[data-spec=value]', 0)->innertext; 
    $result['meta'] ['product-name'] ['item'] = $html->find('td[data-spec=value1]', 0)->innertext;
```

I would like to show you like this

```
    "meta": {
            "product-name": [
                  {
                      "item":"art 200",
                      "item":"art 300",
                      "item":"art 300"
                   },
                    {
                      "item":"art 200",
                      "item":"art 300",
                      "item":"art 300"
                   }
             ],
```

but it only displays one item

Answer (score 0):

If your code is PHP then the last `$result['meta'] ['product-name'] ['item'] =` is overwriting the first result.  Change both lines to
`$result['meta'] ['product-name'] ['item'] [] =`

Comment: thank you much

actually the code continues like this:


"product-name": [
              {
                  "item":"art 200",
                  "icon":"art 300",
                  "value":"art 300"
               },
                {
                  "item":"art 200",
                  "icon":"art 300",
                  "value":"art 300"
               }
         ],

it just overwrites me like you said.


I tried yours but it attracts like this 0,1,

"product-name": {
            "item": "art 200",
            "0": "art 300",
            "1": "art 300"